# Reverse Modulus Operator

Tags: reverse, modulus

**Over 3 years after asking the question I found the solution.  I have included it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735393).**

I have an expression with modulus in it that needs to be put in terms of x.

(a + x) mod m = b

I can't figure out what to do with the modulus.  Is there a way to get x by itself, or am I out of luck on this one?

**Edit**: I realize that I can get multiple answers, but I'm looking for an answer that falls within the range of m.

Comment: You may try to use The Chinese Remainder Theorem.
Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5RcMWiUyyE).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was revisiting this question and realized it is possible based off of the answer @Gorcha gave.

```
(a + x) mod m = b  
a + x = nm + b  
x = nm + b - a for some integer n
```

I don't know why I didn't realize it before but the solution can be derived by setting n to 0.

The answer to my question then appears to be `x = b - a`, though in the example `(26 + x) mod 29 = 3` the result is -23, which is less than m.  To get -23 back in the expected range mod it with 29, which gives 6.  While not specified in the question this gives a value between 0 and m.

The final solution then becomes: `x = (b - a) mod m`

I.E.

```
(26 + x) mod 29 = 3
x = (3 - 26) mod 29
x = -23 mod 29
x = 6
```

Which puts x in the range of 0 to m.  Checking will show `(26 + 6) mod 29 = 3`.

Comment: Technically you don't have to set n to 0.  Any n appears to work.  I.E.  x = (nm + b - a) mod m will give the correct answer of x for any integer n.

Comment: What about `26x mod 29 = 3` ?

Comment: How does that help solve for x within the range of 0 to m?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see.  I'm not entirely sure.  Wolfram Alpha says x = 29n + 28 for some integer n but I haven't been able to work out why.

Comment: A note: "setting n to 0" is a good assumption for some problems. Exactly speaking considering nm to be 0 is good assumption, since nm is divisible by m, for those kind of problems.

Comment: I know this is 2 years after. But the correct answer would be `x = 29 * n + 6`, where `n in Z`

Answer (score 15):

You can't definitively figure out x, but we can get a bit further given the definition of the operator.

```
x mod y = z if x = ny + z for some integer n, where 0 <= z < y
```

So in your case:

```
(a + x) mod m = b
a + x = nm + b
x = nm + b - a for some integer n
```

Answer (score 7):

yep. you're screwed.

example:

```
5 mod 3 = 2
8 mod 3 = 2
```

so inverse mod 2 is what? 8 or 5? or 11? or an infinitude of other numbers?

Inverse mod is a relation, you start to get to more tricky mathematics if you try to pursue this. If you're in haskell you could easilyish model it with non-determinism (an infinite list of possible answers)

Also, this isn't really a programming question. check out math exchange.

Comment: Haha, just saw your edit. in the end i think you've thrown away too much info by applying modulus. It's a bit of an event horizon

Comment: Right, I was hoping someone smarter than myself had a convenient solution, but I had almost come to this conclusion by myself before hand.  Thx bout the tip about math exchange, I didn't know it existed till today!

Answer (score 2):

I have this Equation to reverse the modulus
if we have

```
(var1 +var2) mod num=Res
```

then to get

```
var1= num-((Res-var2)*-1)
```

e.g. `25+5mod26=4`

```
var1=26-((4-5)*-1)
var1=26-1
var1=5
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part about this equation is that even if you know a, m, and b, you can not conclusively figure out x.

For example, say your equation was:

```
(2 + x) % 4 = 3
```

x could be 1, 5, 9, 13 etc.

This means you are out of luck, there is no way to get x by itself.

Comment: Except that I'm looking for a value within the range of m, so it would only be 1, since 5, 9 and 13 are all outside the range I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using `@Subhi Anyman` answer as reference (with slight modifications), if we have this equation to reverse the modulus operation

```
 (var1 + var2) mod num = Res
```

then to obtain `var1`, we use the following

```
var1 = num - ((Res - var2) * -1)
if (var1 > num) {
   var1 = var % num;          // making sure var1 is in range of 'num'
}
```