# Reverse mathematic equation

Tags: math, equation

Does anyone know how to reverse this equation when only Y, Z are known? I want to know what X is.

(X + Y) % 62 = Z

Comment: Maybe try on http://math.stackexchange.com/. And you want to *solve* this equation, not reverse it.

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133194/reverse-modulus-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(X + Y) % 62 = Z
```

means that X+Y = 62*n + Z for arbitrary integer n, from that follows

```
X = 62*n+Z-Y
```

where n can be any integer value, if you need single solution you can pick arbitrary one or if  you have any extra limitations on X value you'll need to find X that satisfies them

Answer (score 4):

```
X = Z - Y + 62*n
```

where n is any integer.