# How to calculate the modular multiplicative inverse for the Affine Cipher

Tags: c#, .net, math, modulo

I am trying to create a small software that does the Affine Cipher, which means that **K1** and the amount of letters in the alphabet (using **m** for this number) must be coprime, that is `gcd(k1, m) == 1`.

Basically it's like this:

I have a plaintext: **hey**

I have K1: **7**

I have K2: **5**

Plaintext in numerical format is:
**8 5 25**

8 - from h (the position in the alphabet) and **
5 25** goes the same for **e** and **y**

Encrypted: **7 13 18**

Which is the formula:

**k1  * 8 + k2 mod 27** = 7

**k1  * 5 + k2 mod 27** = 13

**k1  * 25 + k2 mod 27** = 18

I have a function that crypts this but I don't know how to decrypt.

For example I have 7 for h. I want to get the number 8 back again, knowing 7, k1 and k2.

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Some function where you input k1, k2, result (7 for example, for h), and it gives me back 8, but I really don't know how to reverse this.

The function for encryption is this:

```
public List<int> get_crypted_char(string[] strr)
        {
            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < strr.Length; i++)
            {
                int ch = int.Parse(strr[i]);
                int numberback = k1 * ch + 5;
                numberback = (numberback % 27);
                l.Add(numberback);
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Where: string[] strr is a string that contains the plaintext. 
**Function example:**
get_crypted_char({"e","c","b"})

The result would be a list like this {"5","3","2"}

**UPDATE:**
Here is a link from wikipedia about this encryption, and also decryption, but ... I don't really understand "how to"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher

Comment: Your question is not clear IMO..

Comment: Do you have the encryption code? I think it's easier to read.

Comment: This has been asked and answered in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10133236/146205. There is no real way of getting that back, as `8 mod 3` and `5 mod 3` both equal `2`, for example.

Comment: Knowing the result of a mod operation isn't going to help you finding the operands. For instance `61 mod 27 = 7` but also `34 mod 27 = 7` or even `7 mod 27 = 7`. So how will you know which of the zillion possibilities is the correct one?

Comment: The link has the decryption algorithm.   And why are you using 27?

Comment: in my case I have to use 27.
In the link, in the decryption algorithm I don't know from where 21 comes. it seems like it's a at -1, but don't know from where

Comment: @icebox19 Have a look at my answer, it's a working solution. But please take a math class, maybe you shouldn't really be dealing with cyphers? :)

Comment: @JensenSomers That is a totally different case, in this case the values are coprime.

Comment: @jyparask They are coprime, as stated by the algorithm. (But not in the header though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (in general case, for affine cipher, see update below). That's why module operation is so frequently used in security algorithms - it is not reversible. But, why don't we try?

```
result = (k1 * input + k2) % 27 (*1)
```

Let's take the first letter:

```
result = (7 * 8 + 5) % 27 = 7
```

That's cool. Now, because we said, that:

```
result = (k1 * input + k2) % 27
```

the following is also true:

```
k1 * input + k2 = 27 * div + result (*2)
```

where

```
div = (k1 * input + k2) / 27 (integral division)
```

It is quite obvious (if a % b = c, then a = b*n + c, where n is the result of integer division a/b).

You know the values of k1 (which is 7), k2 (5) and result (7). So, when we put these values to (*2), we get the following:

```
7 * input + 5 = 27 * div + 7 //You need to solve this
```

As you can see, it is impossible to solve this, because you would need to know also the result of the integral division - translating this to your function's language, you would need the value of

```
numberback / 27
```

which is unknown. So answer is: **you cannot reverse your function's results, using only output it returns**.

---

** UPDATE **

---

I focused too much on the question's title, so the answer above is not fully correct. I decided not to remove it, however, but write an update.

So, the answer **for your particular case** (affine cipher) is: YES, you can reverse it.

As you can see on the wiki, decryption function for affine cipher for the following encrytption function:

```
E(input) = a*input + b mod m
```

is defined as:

```
D(enc) = a^-1 * (enc - b) mod m
```

The only possible problem here can be computation of a^-1, which is modular multiplicative inverse.

Read about it on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), I will provide only example.

In your case a = k1 = 7 and m = 27. So:

```
7^-1 = p mod 27
7p = 1 mod 27
```

In other words, you need to find p, which satisfies the following: 7p % 27 = 1.
p can be computed using extended euclidean algorithm and I computed it to be 4 (4 * 7 = 28, 28 % 27 = 1).

Check, if can decipher your output now:

```
E(8) = 7*8 + 5 mod 27 = 7

D(7) = 4 * (7 - 5) mod 27 = 8
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @icebox19 The answer is incorrect though. The Cipher required coprimes.

Comment: You are making the same assumption as @Stefan, the numbers are not random. `k1` and `m` (27) are coprime, do not forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the other answers do not take into account the the algorithm at hand is the Affine Cipher, ie there are some conditions at hand, the most important one the coprime status of `k1` and `m`.

In your case it would be:

```
m = 27; // letters in your alphabet
k1 = 7; // coprime with m
k2 = 5; // no reqs here, just that a value above 27 is the same as mod 27 of that value

int Encrypt(int letter) {
  return ((letter * k1) + k2) % m;
}

int Decrypt(int letter) {
  return ((letter - k2) * modInverse(k1, m)) % m;
}

Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>> extendedEuclid(int a, int b)
{
  int x = 1, y = 0;
  int xLast = 0, yLast = 1;
  int q, r, m, n;
  while (a != 0)
  {
    q = b / a;
    r = b % a;
    m = xLast - q * x;
    n = yLast - q * y;
    xLast = x; yLast = y;
    x = m; y = n;
    b = a; a = r;
  }
  return new Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>(b, new Tuple<int, int>(xLast, yLast));
}

int modInverse(int a, int m)
{
  return (extendedEuclid(a, m).Item2.Item1 + m) % m;
}
```

ModInverse implementation taken from http://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/modular-multiplicative-inverse/.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a program that will tell the modular inverse of something. I will let you use it. It is posted below.

```
# Cryptomath Module


def gcf(a, b):
    # Return the GCD of a & b using Euclid's Algorithm
    while a != 0:
        a, b = b % a, a
    return b


def findModInverse(a, m):
    # Return the modular inverse of a % m, which is
    # the number x such that a*x % m = 1

    if gcf(a, m) != 1:
        return None # No mode inverese if a & m aren't relatively prime

    # Calculate using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3 # // is the integer division operator
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q *
v3), v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m
```

Note: The modular inverse is found using the extended euclidean algorithm. Here is the Wikipedia entry for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm.

Note: This needs to be imported as a module to be used. Hope it helps.