# Using Euclidean algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, modulus

If I have `x= 11` and `y = 6` and I want to calculate 
`(w*x)mod(y) = 1` . In other words how can I calculate the number that if multiplied by 11 and then modulus 6 the result 1. In this case w should be equal to 5.
Is there anyway I can calculate the w in a method using Euclidean algorithm in java?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Modulus Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133194/reverse-modulus-operator)

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that says that the linear congruence `a * x = b (mod n)`, where `a, b`, and `n` are integers, has a solution *if and only if* `gcd(a, n) = 1`.

Since `gcd(11,6) = 1`, which is simply because 11 is a prime number, your equation is indeed solvable.

To answer the question, no, you cannot *solve* the linear congruence using Euclid's algorithms---however, you can do that using *extended* Euclid's algorithm---, but you can use it so verify that the equation is solvable.

Once you find that `gcd(a,n)=1`, you compute the solution as `x = b*r mod n`, where `r = a^-1 (mod n)`. To compute the inverse of `a`, which here we denoted `r`, you can use the *extended* Euclidean algorithm (abbreviated EEA).

If `gcd(a,n)=1`, then EEA, given `a` and `n`, computes `r` and `s` such that `a*r + n*s = 1`. We claim that `r` is the inverse of `a` modulo `n`. Once you have `r`, you compute `x = b * r mod n`.

These algorithms are nicely described in the book *Introduction to Algorithm* by Cormen et al.